# Implementation of global shared counter

Tags: concurrency, x86, memory-barriers

the following code comes from (Listing 5.3):
[Is Parallel Programming Hard, And, If So, What Can You Do About It?](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.html)

```
DEFINE PER_THREAD(long, counter);

void inc_count(void){
  __get_thread_var(counter)++; // __get_thread_var returns a reference to thread local counter.  
}

long read_count(void){
    int t;
    long sum = 0;

    for_each_thread(t)
       sum += per_thread(counter, t);
    return sum;
}
```

Above code implements a global (shared by cores) counter. We could use atomic operations instead, obviously. However, we consider the case where updates are very frequent so we need a per-thread variable to minimize traffic on CPU system.

I cannot grasp why it is correct. After all, In `C/C++/Java` we have at most `SC-DRF` (Sequential Consistency if there is no data race).

Actually, we have a datarace. In a result we have no guarantee from a memory model. Especially, what about `Out Of Air Thin values`? I cannot see how it is guaranteed that it does not happen. So, what do you think? Is that implementation correct in the terms of my doubts, and why?

Comment: `__get_therad_var` looks like a typo.  Was that really in the original?  Anyway, obviously you can only run `read_count` after all the writing threads have stopped, if you want to avoid data-race UB.  Otherwise it's UB, but in practice on normal systems sort of ok because a naturally-aligned `long` load happens to be atomic on most platforms.  But not safe from optimizing away if called in a loop...

Comment: @PeterCordes, I've edited.

Comment: "_Out Of Air Thin values_" are allowed by the (inane, broken, useless) C++ semantics for relaxed atomics. They cannot occur in the real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which version of the document you are referring to but figure 5.3 in the [latest one](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.2018.12.08a.pdf) uses the macros `READ_ONCE` and `WRITE_ONCE` which provide basic visibility guarantees across threads. When combined with proper alignment of `counter`, then I suppose it is essentially the equivalent of relaxed atomic semantics.